# Understanding the ending particle がね

Tags: grammar

> 「シン君とライデン君は、つきあい長いから。私達と会う前にも、色々あったみたいだし」
>
> 「まあねー」
>
> 「そうなのかの？」
>
> 「拳と拳でわかりあったとかいう、マンガみたいな恥ずかしいエピソードとか**がね**。帰ったらライデンに聞いてみなよ」
>
> ……と。
>
> 物陰から背の高さ順にアンジュ、セオ、フレデリカと頭半分だけ覗かせて、三人はひそひそ言葉を交わす。
>
> ちなみに物陰とは礼拝堂の入口までゆっくりこっそり移動してきたファイドのコンテナの陰で、残ったクレナはアンジュに羽交い絞めにされて片手で口を塞がれて、何やらムームー言っている。
>
> 言い争っている様子の二人を見るなり犬みたいにふっとんで行こうとしたのを、アンジュがとっ捕まえて押さえている次第である。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉 安里アサト

The four people saw シン and ライデン quarreling and one of them said it was like manga scene.

How should I understand the ending particle combination of the がね?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the usual subject particle が + the ending particle ね (like that in the preceding まあね). As such it could be が alone, i.e. "エピソードとかが". "あった" is omitted at the end.

The sentence elaborates on "色々あった", saying "拳と拳でわかりあったとかいう、マンガみたいな恥ずかしいエピソードとか" is one instance of 色々.