# Ending particle がね?

Tags: grammar

> 毒を抜くのに手間どってしまいましてまアあんなものカレーうどんの染みを抜くのに比べれば楽なものでしたがね

What is the function of がね here?
I can't find anything about the ending particle がね online or in books.

Closest thing I found was in this question:
[Understanding the ending particle がね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95504/understanding-the-ending-particle-%e3%81%8c%e3%81%ad)
Though I don't think it is related to my question

Answer (score 3):

> まアあんなものカレーうどんの染みを抜くのにべれば楽なものでした**がね**。

The が is a 接続助詞 (conjunctive particle) meaning "though", similar to 「～けど」「～けれど」.

The ね is a 終助詞 (sentence-ending particle) / 間投助詞 (interjectory particle), or a filler.

You can rewrite the sentence like this:

> 毒を抜くのに手間どってしまいまして。まア、あんなもの(は、)カレーうどんの染みを抜くのに比べれば楽なものでした**が(ね)**。 ≈ けど(ね)。

"It took time to remove the poison. Well, it was easier than removing curry udon stains**, though.**"

---

The が in the linked question is a 格助詞 (case particle), which attaches to a 体言 (名詞 nouns, 代名詞 pronouns, etc.), while the 接続助詞「が」 attaches to 活用語の終止形 (the terminal form of conjugatable words, such as verbs, adjectives, auxiliaries).

Comment: Just want to make sure, the usage of がね in the original question is still widely used right?

Comment: @asyrafshaari Yeah, I don't think it's something special or classical. I think ～ですけどね sounds a bit softer and more colloquial and is more widely used in daily conversation.